# New User Account has no password even sudo passwd accountname

Tags: login, password

I created a new user account without a password.

I later used the GUI and Terminal methods to add a password to this new account. I have tried several time with reboots, logout/login after adding the new password both from the root/administrator account and even this new user account.

The user still does not need to enter a password at the login screen.

Any next steps / ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you include the output of the terminal command `getent group nopasswdlogin` please?

Comment: nopasswdlogin:x:119:username

Answer (score 3):

It looks like *username* belongs to the `nopasswdlogin` group, which means that only the name is required to log in, regardless of whether a password is actually set for the account (note: this is **not** the same as autologin - which bypasses the login screen altogether).

You should be able to just remove the user from the group e.g. with terminal command

```
sudo gpasswd --delete username nopasswdlogin
```

Answer (score 0):

When logged in as the user, go to

`System Settings > User Accounts > My Account`

and make sure "Automatic Login" is set to "OFF".

Comment: Automatic Login is set to OFF